# Яка різниця між словами "льотний", "літаючий", "летючий" та "літальний"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Нещодавно слухаючи новини почув вислів "летючий апарат". Однак, я завжди гадав, що потрібно казати "літаючий апарат" (наприклад, розшифрування [НЛО](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%27%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82) - неопізнаний літаючий об'єкт).

Перш за все вирішив пошукати слова в СУМі, де знайшов їхні визначення:

[Летючий](http://sum.in.ua/s/letjuchyj):

> Який має здатність пересуватися в повітрі за допомогою крил.
>
> (Також там є вислів "**летюча фортеця**", а також "**летюча миша**")

[Літаючий](http://sum.in.ua/s/litajuchyj):

> Який вміє літати, має засоби для пересування в повітрі.
>
> (Тут же бачимо вислів "**літаюча фортеця**" і також "**літаюча миша**"
>   (в прикладі)).

[Льотний](http://sum.in.ua/s/ljotnyj):

> Здатний літати (про комах, птахів і т. ін.).

[Літальний](http://sum.in.ua/s/Litaljnyj):

> Який використовується для літання.
>
> (У прикладі бачимо "**літальний апарат**")

На Вікіпедії знайшов статтю про "[летюче авто](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE)", але у тій же статті є посилання на "[літальний апарат](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82)". Також є такі статті як "[летючий прут](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82_(%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%8F))", "[летючий голандець](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)", "[летючий дракон](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD)", але "[літаючий диск](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA)" і навіть "[літаючий автомобіль](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C)" (однак, там пише, що є пропозиція об'єднати цю статтю із статею про "летюче авто").

Тому і виникло питання чи є між цими словами взагалі якась різниця (коли ми говоримо про те, що якийсь об'єкт чи істота вміє літати).

Спробував шукати синоніми до слова "літаючий", після чого знайшов сайт, де був [Словник синонімів](http://uk.synonymfinder.net/sinonimiv/l/litalnij), одак, здається, що інформація на ньому може бути перекладена із якогось російського джерела, бо як інакше пояснити, що слова "авіація", "льотний" та "пілотування" у ньому позначені як синоніми.

Comment: А ще _леткий_ :).

Comment: І _літний_ (не плутати з _літній_); і _польотний_.

Comment: @Sasha, гадаєте, варто їх також додати в питання?

Comment: Необов'язково, звісно, але було б добре.

Answer (score 3):

Здається вдалося знайти відповідь. В [Літературному слововживанні](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53403/31265.html) пише:

> **Леткий.** Який має здатність швидко зникати, поширюючись у повітрі або випаровуючись: летка мазь, леткі речовини.
>
> **Летючий.** Переважно який має здатність пересуватися в повітрі за допомогою крил, а також вітру, поштовху тощо: летюча бджола, летюча
>   риба, летючий пісок, летючий сніг, летючі міни.
>
> **Летучий.** 1. Який літає, летить, переміщується в повітрі: летучий дим, летучі піски. 2. Те саме, що леткий: летучі кислоти, летучі
>   речовини, летучі продукти.

І також на [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8F:%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%27%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82_%E2%86%92_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%27%D1%94%D0%BA%D1%82) є цікава думка:

> Погоджуюсь, що об'єкт необов'язково є пристосованим для польотів, отже
>   краще казати летючий (ми лиш знаємо, що він летів на той момент, коли
>   його бачили), і непізнаний в даному випадку не дуже гарне слово.

А також взяв інформацію із двої форумів присвячених українській мові ([Словник ЮА](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=4107) і [R2u](https://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=657&start=10)).

Тобто виходить, що якщо ми говоримо про апарат, який може літати (має для цього спеціальне обладнання), то ми можемо вживати слово "**летючий**" або "**літаючий**".

"**Літальний**" - призначений для літання.

Якщо ж щось літає саме собою, то краще вживати лише слово "**летючий**" ("Летючий голандець" плаває без екіпажу, летюча риба та дракон літають без допомоги додаткового обладнання тощо) або "**леткий**" (якщо говоримо про речовини, кислоти тощо).

Answer (score 3):

Взагалі ні, "**літаючий**" ми вживати не можемо, тому що це активний дієприкметник на -ючий — конструкція, невластива українській. Натомість окрім "**летючий**" можемо ще використовувати "**летячий**", "**льотовий**" чи "**літний**" (відповідно до словника Кримського, Єфремова, 1924–33рр.).

Також дивись у «Словнику-довіднику з українського літературного слововживання» С. І. Головащука (наприклад, на [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/32/53403/31291.html)):

> **Літний**, -а, -є. Який стосується польоту: *літна погода*.

Comment: Зазначу, що на активні дієприкметники є різні погляди.

Comment: Як на мене, то *літний* більше схоже на пасив.